# Azure Function - 404 error while acquiring Host lock lease

Tags: azure-functions

I have created Azure Function v4.2 with .NET 6.0, during function startup I am getting 404 error while acquiring Host lock lease raised from `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.ReadLeaseBlobMetadata`.

If I comment out the `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting in *local.settings.json* the error goes away but the function gives error during execution.

This is not the first function project I have created, a number of others seemed to work and showed the message `Host lock lease acquired by instance ID` fine in the console. I can't seem to figure out what is unique with this project and a few others which are giving this error.

The error details are as follows:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Service request failed.
Status: 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)
ErrorCode: BlobNotFound

Headers:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 3f8b3a43-201e-008b-32d1-bf4f6a000000
x-ms-client-request-id: e281a4a0-e29c-4303-8462-933417700046
x-ms-version: 2021-08-06
x-ms-error-code: BlobNotFound
Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 14:56:22 GMT

  Source=Azure.Storage.Blobs
  StackTrace:
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.<GetPropertiesInternal>d__119.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__118.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.<ReadLeaseBlobMetadata>d__19.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage\Singleton\BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs:line 337

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.ReadLeaseBlobMetadata(Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient, System.Threading.CancellationToken) in BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure.RequestFailedException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Service request failed.
> Status: 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)
> ErrorCode: BlobNotFound

- The issue seems to be related to the Azure Storage account. Azure Functions runtime uses storage account to handle the distributed locks which are required to execute functions.
- When the function app starts, it tries to acquire a lease on the host to make sure only one instance is running at a time. If it cannot acquire the lease, it leads to 404 error.

**Check the below steps :**

1. Azure functions uses the container `azure-webjobs-hosts` to manage the lease. Make sure you have `azure-webjobs-hosts` in storage account.

[image]

2. Make sure the blob/container you are trying to use in your Azure function is available in the Storage account.
3. Make sure storage account has all the necessary permissions.
4. Check if the connection string value of your storage account in  `local.settings.json`  is correct.
5. Ensure that the Blob you are pointing to is not deleted in the storage account.

Check by modifying  `local.setting.json` as below:

- Add "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" as value of "AzureWebJobsStorage".

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"connection":"your_storage_connection_string"
}
}
```

3. Make sure the Blob name you are using in the function and the Blob created in the Storage account is same.
4. If still doesn't work, try with new storage account (or) blob.

Comment: The URL being checked was https://{STORAGE_ACC}.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts/locks/cpcarungjcrk9-707881903/host. This was not present, I was able to create the blob at the path manually and it started to work! But is this the right approach? How is this blob normally created?

Also, the new function project is migrated from the older one based on Azure Function 1.0 using .NET 4.6. The older function executed fine and I did see the message "Host lock lease acquired by instance ID.." in the console (without creating the blob manually), why was this?

Comment: This `azure-webjobs-hosts` [blob](https://i.imgur.com/KZe6zwc.png) usually gets created and managed by the Functions runtime itself.  Manually creating this blob can be a workaround in case of any issues but not recommended. Refer answers in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75161243/i-dont-have-a-azure-webjobs-hosts-container-in-azure-storage-explorer-theref#:~:text=azure%2Dwebjobs%2Dhosts%20is%20a,webjobs%2Dhosts%20container%2Ffolder.) to know about `azure-webjobs-hosts`.

Comment: I proceeded with the workaround of creating the blob manually but couldn't figure out why the runtime couldn't create the entry.